# session generator not working for Authlogic in Rails 3.Help me out !

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authlogic

I installed authlogic and created a signup mechanism.And for creating a sign in mechanism
I tried to generate the session controlers as below but rails 3 throws error as follows.
How do I create the user_session and proceed with authlogic in rails 3 ?

```
:~/work_space/rails_apps/sample_authentication$ rails generate session user_session  
Could not find generator session
```

Comment: Did you edit Authlogic to your gem file and do a bundle install?

Comment: Yeah i added the lines gem "authlogic" and 
gem "rails3-generators" in my Gemfile and did a bundle install.And was able to use up signup functionality of authlogic.

Comment: Also version of authlogic gem are you using ?

Comment: Using authlogic (2.1.6) 
Using bundler (1.0.0) 
Using thor (0.14.3) 
Using railties (3.0.0) 
Using rails (3.0.0) 
Using rails3-generators (0.14.0)

Comment: I also tried to manually  add the model view and controller files that would be generated by the session generator script and when I try to test my app am getting the following error.                       Model UserSession does not respond to name  

Extracted source (around line #5):  
     <% form_for :user_session, @user_session, :url => { :action =>   "create" } do |f| %>  
     <p>  
        <%= f.label :name %><br />  
        <%= f.text_field :name %>  <<<< error points to this line
     </p>  
     <p>  
         <%= f.label :password %><br />

Answer (score 1):

as for the time being the generator for session still doesn't work with rails 3. However here

https://github.com/jonathandean/authlogic_example

the tutorial in the readme explains how to use authlogic (and generate a session-model) with rails 3. Basically all you have to do is to generate a normal model.